# How to use push view navigation programmatically?

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

I have following 4 view controllers:

1. Home
2. Groups
3. Items
4. Details

I am using modal view navigation for 'Home -> Groups' and 'Groups -> Items'. Now, I want to use push view controller for 'Items -> Details'. Because, I am passing group id for 'Groups -> Items' to display group specific items. So, 'Items' is dynamic. I do not want to reproduce 'Items' for 'Details -> Items' for back to items from details.

How can I achieve it?

EDIT

Here is code to display items page:

```
@implementation RpFoodList
@synthesize gid;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadFoodList];
}

- (void) loadFoodList
{
    RpDb *rpDb = [[RpDb alloc] init];

    int groupID = [self gid];

    UIImage *iconLeft = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_left.png"];
    UIImage *iconLeftH = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_left_h.png"];
    UIButton *btnLeft;
    UIButton *button;
    UILabel *sep;

    int bulletWidth = 40;
    int rowHeight = 32;

    NSMutableArray *foods = [rpDb getGroupFoods:groupID];

    [groupTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Group Details (%d)", [foods count]]];

    int counter = 0;
    int contentSize = 0;

    for(NSMutableDictionary *food in foods)
    {        
        NSNumber *foodID = [food valueForKey:@"foodID"];
        int tag = [foodID intValue];
        NSNumber *groupID = [food valueForKey:@"groupID"];
        NSString *foodName = [food valueForKey:@"foodName"];
        NSString *foodNameAr = [food valueForKey:@"foodNameAr"];

        btnLeft = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        btnLeft.frame = CGRectMake(0, rowHeight*counter+1, bulletWidth, rowHeight);
        [btnLeft setImage:iconLeft forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnLeft setImage:iconLeftH forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [btnLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(showFoodDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btnLeft.tag = tag;

        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(bulletWidth, rowHeight*counter+1, self.view.frame.size.width-bulletWidth, rowHeight);
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitle:foodNameAr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 10);

        counter++;

        contentSize += rowHeight + 1;

        sep = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [sep setFrame:CGRectMake(0, rowHeight*counter+1, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];
        [sep setBackgroundColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor]];

        [scrollView addSubview:button];
        [scrollView addSubview:btnLeft];
        [scrollView addSubview:sep];
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, contentSize);

}

- (IBAction)showFoodDetails:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    RpFoodDetails *foodDetails = (RpFoodDetails*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RpFoodDetails"];
    foodDetails.fid = [sender tag];
    foodDetails.gid = [self gid];
    [self presentModalViewController:foodDetails animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that when you go back from Details you are worried that you won't know what items to display? If that is your concern that won't be an issue as the view controller will still be in the stack

Comment: I am not able to understand your question.

Comment: Yes. When I back to items from details, blank screen is appearing. I have used 'navigation bar' and 'bar button item' for back button.

Comment: @Mosiur What happens in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` of `Items` VC? Are you reloading items by calling WS or through DB? Show your code.

Comment: @Amar I have edited the question to provide the code. pls check.

Comment: @Mosiur Why are you using `presentModalViewController`? In your case you should use `UINavigationController`. Multiple modal view controllers being presented doesn't work well.

Comment: @Amar I had used UINavigationController, but clicking on food item, item details page is not appearing.

Comment: I have also applied modal navigation to back button at details page.

Comment: You have to create the `UINavigationController` and set it as `rootController` of your application window. When you create your first VC i.e. `Home`, it should be add as root controller on navigation. Then rest of the VCs will need to be pushed onto navigation stack.

Comment: @Mosiur I'd suggest reading some basic tutorials on `UINavigationController` for better understanding.

Comment: @Amar Is it not possible to have some modal navigation and some push navigation?

Comment: @Mosiur It is possible but your case I don't see any navigation controller used.

Comment: I have applied push navigation for all view controllers. But, It would be helpful if I can apply push navigation to details page only.

Answer (score 0):

its simple from my understanding you need group class and items class and from group you pass group object to items and produce item object NSArray and populate UITable view and then pass same object of item to detail page and when you will come back from detail page to items page all items will be in array and populated for you until you will go back to group page.

I answer from my understanding of question

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, you have array of **groups** which consist of array of **items**.

NSMutableArray *foods = [rpDb getGroupFoods:groupID];

This line returns array of items based on your group id.

So in Items detail VC, you need to pass foodId from Items VC.

To make it dynamic in nature, you need to call Database related operation in viewWillAppear. Moreover flush out the old data from your array also.